# Porting Python/Matlab to C and to fixed-point DSP processor - should C be in fixed-point too?

Tags: c, neural-network, deep-learning, signal-processing, fixed-point

I have a Python/Matlab code that does intensive Neural Network calculations. This Python/Matlab code will eventualy be ported to several target (fixed-point) DSP processor platforms (ARM, Tensillica, etc.). As an in-between step, the Python/Matlab code should be first ported to C on an x86 platform, thus becoming a sorf of a "reference" code.

The question is, should this C code be written in normal floating-point, or, **does it bring any benefits for future DSP ports to write it immediately on x86 in fixed-point**?

Comment: I would say it's better to just stick with the fixed point so you get any scaling/range issues out of the way, since you'll have to do that anyways if you go from fixed -> float -> fixed

Comment: How do you get fixed-point numbers in C?

Comment: @JL2210 you keep the number of fractional bits in your head. I think some people have written libraries, but you don't really need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend implementing you algorithm in fixed-point now.  One tool that I have used to test my fixed-point implementations against Python floating-point reference implementations is [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to directly call your C functions from your Python code for direct comparison.

For example, to use ctypes you must compile your fixed-point C functions into a shared object

```
gcc -shared -std-gnu11 -g -o $(BIN_DIR)/libfm.so src/fxpt_atan2.c
```

Then in your Python file

```
import scipy as sp
import ctypes as ct

# Bind functions in shared object so they can be called in Python.
fm = ct.CDLL('../build/x86/bin/libfm.so')

# Create floating point reference.
N = 1024
n = sp.arange(N)
x = sp.exp(2*sp.pi*1j*n/N)
phi = sp.arctan2(sp.imag(x), sp.real(x))

# Quantize input and process with fixed-point implementation.
x_q, scale = quantize(x, normalize='pow2')
phi_q = sp.zeros(len(x), dtype=sp.int16)
for n in range(len(x)):
    # Call ctypes bound function from shared object.
    x_re_q = ct.c_int16(int(sp.real(x_q[n])))
    x_im_q = ct.c_int16(int(sp.imag(x_q[n])))
    phi_q[n] = fm.fxpt_atan2(x_im_q, x_re_q)

# Compare floating point reference and fixed-point implementation.
print(sp.allclose(phi, phi_q/scale*sp.pi, rtol=1e-3))
```

Comment: ctypes looks interesting. How did you actualy compare the two outputs?

Comment: In you Python file that is generating your reference data and calling you fixed-pint implementation, you can use numpy.allclose to check if fixed-point output is equal to reference within a given tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in fixed point now, if you have the time and if your particular algorithm allows for it. You'll be able to get an apples to apples comparison for accuracy and performance when comparing across platforms.

I'd also consider lowering down your bitrate to be whatever your final platform will be. So if you'll be using a 16-bit ADC etc, I'd make your functions accept and work with 16 bit integers now. If this is unknown, then it's probably best to stick to 32.

Note that you'll likely be able to copy a majority of the C code directly to your final platform. So it makes sense to put in the time now (if your timeline allows it).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your dynamic range requriements but if 32 bit fixed point is enought then I'd concur with all the suggestions to go straight for that.
Also, fstop_22's recommendation of ctype is excellent.
Finally, I don't know how familiar you are with fixed point programming but I always try to use [Q Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)) if possible. Q8.24 is always a good starting point because it gives you headroom for your numbers to grow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which kind of Matlab/Python libraries you are using, but most likely they will support some kind of fixed point configuration. For example, tensorflow supports this through `quantize`. So I don't how hard it will be for you to have that code side running with fixed point representation, but I would say it is totally worth to spend some time on it. You can also explore about `fixed point training` which is a technique that takes into account during the training phase, that you will work with fixed point representation later on. There are some papers about that.

But answering to your question, I would never deploy a model in a fixed point 16-bit DSP without testing its performance before, and you can easily test it beforehand "faking" that you work with fixed point in Matlab/Python. Also, this can help you to take some decisions when porting your code to C (i.e. how many bits you reserve for the decimal part?) or maybe you can play with different types of quantizations techniques and pick the one that has the lowest impact in a huge dataset, `stochastic rounding` might be also a concept that come in handy for this.